# C# return different object and use it

Tags: c#

I am stuck on a problem.
I have one method to query the tables. And I have classes that represent the table, all of them derive from an interface `ITable`. The method returns `IEnumerable<ITable>`. But I can't use the object given by the return, here is what I mean:

```
public interface ITable 
{
}

public class table1 : ITable
{ 
   prop1 {get;set;} 
}

public class table2 : ITable
{
    prop2 {get; set;}
}

public IEnumerable<ITable> GetInfo(string table)
{
    switch(table)
    { 
        case "Table1": 
            var dataTable1 = connection.Query<Table1> ....
            return dataTable1;
        case "Table2": 
            var dataTable2 = connection.Query<Table2> ....
            return dataTable2;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var table in listOfTable)
    {
        var data = GetInfo(table);
        //data here is "Table" how can i make the mthod to return my Table1 or Table2?
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't return data in Main!!

Comment: `GetInfo` seems a bit pointless. Just have two methods that return the strongly typed classes?

Comment: does it matter? I mean, now you can loop data and check if `foreach (var item in data) { if ( item is Table1 table1Item) { ... } }`

Comment: Yes in this case is pointless.. but what if i have 100 tables? i would like to make it a loop instead of having 100 methods..

Comment: do you have 100 tables? This smells of [Gold Plating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_plating_(software_engineering))

Comment: You can use `Cast` when you *know* that all of the items in the enumerable are of a more specific type, but now you've gone full circle because you need to know the *compile time* type there. You're trying to mix runtime information (the value of `table`) with compile-time information (the type you want to work with).

Comment: The more I read this the more confused I am, you want your methods to be both generic and strongly typed? If you want `GetInfo` to be generic then, fine, you've done that. It doesn't make sense to then state that you want the method to also return the strongly typed values. It's either strongly typed or not. You could add a generic but then you will fail the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) of your interface in your method, i.e. if you send `GetInfo<Table1>("table2");`

Comment: If you want a common method to return `IEnumerable<ITable>` why do you expect it to return `IEnumerable<Table1>` instead? I don´t understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to know the specific types, then you're *probably* not making good use of an interface, however: you can do things like:

```
var data = GetInfo(table);
foreach(var item in data)
{
    if (item is table1 t1) { /* special code for table1, now held as t1 */ }
    else if (item is table2 t2) { /* special code for table2, now held as t2 */ }
    else {/* general code for ITable */ }
}
```

Emphasis: you should usually *avoid* needing to know what the specific type is in this scenario. It means you're not actually coding to the interface.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are looking for some generic way to query your database, so you could change the `GetInfo` method to take a type restricted to `ITable` and just return that data, so that your consumer can use the returned data which would now be strongly typed, like

```
public IEnumerable<TTableType> GetInfo<TTableType>() where TTableType: ITable {
  return Connection.Query<TTableType>();
}
```

This would then be callable for all types that implement the `ITable` interface.